# python script instead of browser as client for web socket to django server

Tags: django, websocket

I want to have Python script instead of browser as client and the client should be able to communicate with the server by websockets.

Basically I need the server to notify a python script in some other computer that some new information has arrived. I don't want my client to poll all the time.

Is this possible? Can anybody suggest some reading for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, possible. One option for Python is Autobahn (https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython), which supports Python 2/3 and Twisted as well as asyncio. It allows you to write WebSocket clients.

Comment: thanks. and on the server side i saw two approaches. one is to use socket.io with node.js and other as tornado and django. different people say one is better than other. can you tell me which way is better? with reasons.

Comment: Well, I'd obviously recommend Autobahn on the server as well;) Seriously: you should probably ask a new question for this. But as stated, it'll likely be rejected as "opinion based" ..